# How To Prevent Google Bot (or other Bots) from Submitting my HTML form with previously submitted Information?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have been having problems with my HTML form being falsely submitted by a Bot, which I believe is the Google Bot.

The HTML form is a typical lead generating form. Once submitted, the data is parsed by a php page the saves the data into a typical mysql database and sends the data to the company via an email. A third party vendor script sends the data to a dashboard application when the form is submitted via an onClick event.

The dilemma is that a truly valid form submission, received on a Monday, is then submitted again a few days later.

And, these 'false' submissions are "submitted" in quick succession, usually within a minute or two and usually come in a series of eight.

The hosting server people say it's the Google Bot that is submitting the form with valid information already submitted. These submissions are not the typical spam gibberish.

They suggest using the robots.txt to prevent the Bot from accessing the form and the parsing page. I had done that. I have even put in meta tags to prevent the Bot from accessing the parsing page. It seems like all have failed.

And, upon the 'false' submission, the data is saved to the database and the email with the data is sent to the company.

Yet, the third party script that sends the data to the dashboard is not executed.

So, there are duplicate entries in the data base and the inbox of the company is filled with duplicate entries which they need to sort out.

Is there any help? Have other people experience this? It seems so weird that a Bot can submit a form (if it is really submitting the form or is it somehow reading information from am honest form submission and then submitting the form again to see where the form goes?)

Thanks in advance for any help and insight into this issue.

Comment: Honeypot? CAPTCHA?

Comment: Google "nonce" and "replay attack" - this is a replay attack.

Answer (score 0):

If GoogleBot is truly submitting your forms with fake data, that means [it thinks you have a navigation form, not a contact form](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html).

Make sure the `<form>` is sent only via `method="POST"` and uses typical input `name` attributes such as "name" and "email". Require them to be valid before submission.

As a last resort, PHP can serve the form HTML with a hidden nonce value:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['nonce'] = rand();
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="'.$_SESSION['nonce'].'">';
?>
```

That is checked upon submission:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if ($_POST['nonce'] !== $_SESSION['nonce']) {
    // bad stuff here
  }
  else unset($_SESSION['nonce']); // Prevent double submissions
?>
```